# change Text/DataFormat of Slider's ThumbTooltip

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, slider, tooltip

I have a slider with maximum value of video's time in seconds (1 minute = 60 seconds, so if the video is 60 seconds length, the maximum value of the slider will be 60).

When I drag the Thumb, there's ThumbTooltip that shows the current value I am hovering.
I want to change that text so instead of displaying int, it will display time 1 will be 00:01 and so on...

I tried to play with the style of the Slider with no luck.

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Slider` has `ThumbToolTipValueConverter` property. You need to create class which implements `IValueConverter` interface. In that the `Convert` method will help you to convert the default slider value to your customized value. See the below code.

XAML

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:SliderValueConverter x:Key="SliderValueConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Slider Maximum="60" Value="40" Height="100" Width="300" ThumbToolTipValueConverter="{StaticResource SliderValueConverter}" />
</Grid>
```

SliderValueConverter.cs

```
public class SliderValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var seconds = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

Comment: I did not find `ThumbToolTipValueConverter` in WPF Slider

Comment: This solution is not for WPF. OP has used WPF tag incorrectly. Check this https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/modifying-the-auto-tooltip-of-a-slider/